# Traer fecha desde Sql y Mostrarla en un DateTimePicker en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Tengo un `DateTimePicker` en modo `Custom` así `datetimepicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";`

y para traer los datos de las tablas los traigo con un `ExecuteReader` recorriendo las filas de mi tabla y asignándoselas a variables así:

```
DatosEmpresa.Autorizacion = reader.GetString(0);
DatosEmpresa.Fecha = reader.GetDateTime(1);
```

La cual la variable fecha esta en tipo `DateTime` al igual que mi columna en mi tabla `Sql` donde se guarde la fecha y la hora desde el timepicker, pero al intentar mostrar la fecha en el `DateTimePicker` de esta manera :

```
datetimepicker1.Value = DatosEmpresa.Fecha;
```

no me trae la fecha que esta insertada en la columna, me trae **1/1/0001 0:00:000**

Debido a esto en la ejecución me tira un error:

**El valor de '1/1/0001 0:00:00' no es válido para 'Value'. 'Value' debería estar entre 'MinDate' y 'MaxDate'.**

¿Cómo soluciono este problema y que en el DateTimePicker me muestre la hora que esta en la columna de la tabla de Sql que estoy intentando mostrar? Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.
Esta es la fecha que intento mostrar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿La fecha 1/1/0001 0:00:000 es la que está guardada en la BD? ¿Podrías mostrar tu tabla para ver la fecha que estás intentando asignar a DatosEmpresa.Fecha? También sería bueno ver la consulta en una forma simplificada de la fecha.

Comment: @CarlosPozos ya edite

Comment: ¿Podrías ver qué regresa reader.GetString(1)? Intenta con DatosEmpresa.Fecha = DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString(1))

Comment: @CarlosPozos me regresa la misma fecha que mencione en la pregunta 01/01/0001 1/1/0001 0:00:000

Comment: ¿En SQL cómo es tu consulta? ¿Qué tipo de datos SQL contiene la columna FechaAutorizacion? ¿Es la columna con índice 1? Al parecer el error está al leer de la base de datos. No se está parseando bien. Si con reader.GetString(1) está regresando esa fecha algo pasa con la comunicación entre C# y SQL

Comment: @CarlosPozos lo traigo con un select, en la pregunta dije que era de tipo DateTime el campo

Answer (score 1):

Verifica si `reader.GetDateTime(1)` se esta convirtiendo correctamente en caso contrario obtenerlo como cadena, intenta utilizando la función `ParseExact` para convertir la cadena a `DateTime`

Ejemplo:

```
using System.Globalization;

string dateString=reader.GetString(1);
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DatosEmpresa.Fecha = dateTime;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me dice que no puedo convertir del tipo string a tipo DateTime, de igual forma ya di con mi error, no me estaba leyendo la fila :) muchas gracias